# Java Collections.sort() not comparing elements

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have an ArrayList of IndexEntry's which is a simple class with a string, and two integers and a `compareTo()` method shown below.  My issue is that when I call `Collections.sort()` on the ArrayList most of the time everything sorts correctly, but sometimes two elements will never be compared resulting in an incorrectly sorted list.

Some code for reference:

```
//Get a list of the values
ArrayList<IndexEntry<T>> cleanEntries = new ArrayList<IndexEntry<T>>(matches.get(query).values());

//Sort Files/URLS
Collections.sort(cleanEntries);

public int compareTo(IndexEntry<T> other) {
    if(this.occurrenceCount < other.getOccurrenceCount()){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(this.occurrenceCount > other.getOccurrenceCount()){
        return -1;
    }
    else{//Need to compare Initial Positions
        if(this.firstOccurrence == other.getFirstOccurrence()){
            return this.getLocationName().compareTo(other.getLocationName());
        }
        else if(this.firstOccurrence > other.getFirstOccurrence()){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some example output for all IndexEntry's for the letter "C":

```
c
"index.html", 6, 2
"chickadee.html", 3, 2
"cuckoo.html", 3, 2
"crow.html", 3, 2
"crane.html", 3, 2
"cardinal.html", 3, 2
"quail.html", 2, 2
"robin.html", 2, 2
"finch.html", 2, 2
"kingfisher.html", 2, 2
"swan.html", 2, 2
"turkey.html", 2, 2
"ibis.html", 2, 2
"falcon.html", 2, 2
"albatross.html", 2, 2
"tern.html", 2, 2
"dove.html", 2, 2
"mockingbird.html", 2, 2
"owl.html", 2, 2
"sparrow.html", 2, 2
"hawk.html", 2, 2
"magpie.html", 2, 2
"nighthawk.html", 2, 2
"gull.html", 2, 2
"bluebird.html", 2, 2
"raven.html", 2, 2
"blackbird.html", 2, 2
"sandpiper.html", 2, 2
"pheasant.html", 2, 2
"roadrunner.html", 2, 2
"duck.html", 2, 2
"vulture.html", 2, 2
"pigeon.html", 2, 2
"heron.html", 2, 2
"stork.html", 2, 2
"warbler.html", 2, 2
"woodpecker.html", 2, 2
"hummingbird.html", 2, 2
"mallard.html", 2, 2
"osprey.html", 2, 2
"swallow.html", 2, 2
"wren.html", 2, 2
"goose.html", 2, 2
"meadowlark.html", 2, 2
"pelican.html", 2, 2
"starling.html", 2, 2
"loon.html", 2, 2
"eagle.html", 2, 2
"puffin.html", 2, 2
"egret.html", 2, 2
```

Notice how after the occurrence counts and initial occurrence are determined to be the same it stops sorting.  Correct output would be:

```
c
"index.html", 6, 2
"cardinal.html", 3, 2
"chickadee.html", 3, 2
"crane.html", 3, 2
"crow.html", 3, 2
"cuckoo.html", 3, 2
"albatross.html", 2, 2
"blackbird.html", 2, 2
"bluebird.html", 2, 2
"dove.html", 2, 2
"duck.html", 2, 2
"eagle.html", 2, 2
"egret.html", 2, 2
"falcon.html", 2, 2
"finch.html", 2, 2
"goose.html", 2, 2
"gull.html", 2, 2
"hawk.html", 2, 2
"heron.html", 2, 2
"hummingbird.html", 2, 2
"ibis.html", 2, 2
"kingfisher.html", 2, 2
"loon.html", 2, 2
"magpie.html", 2, 2
"mallard.html", 2, 2
"meadowlark.html", 2, 2
"mockingbird.html", 2, 2
"nighthawk.html", 2, 2
"osprey.html", 2, 2
"owl.html", 2, 2
"pelican.html", 2, 2
"pheasant.html", 2, 2
"pigeon.html", 2, 2
"puffin.html", 2, 2
"quail.html", 2, 2
"raven.html", 2, 2
"roadrunner.html", 2, 2
"robin.html", 2, 2
"sandpiper.html", 2, 2
"sparrow.html", 2, 2
"starling.html", 2, 2
"stork.html", 2, 2
"swallow.html", 2, 2
"swan.html", 2, 2
"tern.html", 2, 2
"turkey.html", 2, 2
"vulture.html", 2, 2
"warbler.html", 2, 2
"woodpecker.html", 2, 2
"wren.html", 2, 2
```

Anyways, like I said I have to omit a lot of information, but if anything comes to mind i'd really appreciate ideas.  It is a fact that the "matches" data structure is not modified after the creation of the ArrayList.

EDIT:
Hey, i'm still reading through your responses.  Thanks so much for the quick help!  Here is the entire IndexEntry Class since a few of you asked:

```
    class IndexEntry<extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<IndexEntry<T>>{
        private T theLocation;
        private Integer occurrenceCount;
        private Integer firstOccurrence;

        public IndexEntry(T location, Integer firstOcc, Integer occCount){
            theLocation = location;
            occurrenceCount = occCount;
            firstOccurrence = firstOcc;
        }

        public int compareTo(IndexEntry<T> other) {         
            if(this.occurrenceCount < other.getOccurrenceCount()){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(this.occurrenceCount > other.getOccurrenceCount()){
                return -1;
            }
            else{//Need to compare Initial Positions
                if(this.firstOccurrence == other.getFirstOccurrence()){
                    return this.getLocationName().compareTo(other.getLocationName());
                }
                else if(this.firstOccurrence > other.getFirstOccurrence()){
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }   

        public String getLocationName(){
            if(theLocation instanceof File){
                return ((File) theLocation).getAbsolutePath();
            }
            else{
                return theLocation.toString();
            }
        }

        public Integer getFirstOccurrence(){
            return firstOccurrence;
        }

        public Integer getOccurrenceCount(){
            return this.occurrenceCount;
        }

        public void addToOccurrenceCount(Integer toAdd){
            occurrenceCount += toAdd;
        }

        public void setFirstOccurrence(Integer firstOcc){
            firstOccurrence = new Integer(firstOcc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your output, do the 3 "fields" correspond to locationName, occurenceCount and firstOccurence (in that order)?

Comment: Unless I am overlooking something, your `compareTo()` method looks like it should work. It could be made a bit simpler by using `Integer.compareTo()` instead of implementing the behavior on the integers yourself, but that does not preclude its correctness. Could you give us some more code, at least so that we can see what the `IndexEntry` class looks like? I am also curious about the use of generics in it (even though it may have nothing to do with your actual problem).

Comment: I'd suggest running your code in a debugger (or with plenty of println statements) using a small input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: A wild guess: in your example output are you printing out locationName exactly? is it possible that the locations you are comparing are file paths (including directories) , which would compare differently than the file names? To avoid further wild guesses, could you show a bit more of the code of `IndexEntry` ?

Comment: More Info: T can be either a file or a string, but in this case it's a string always.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as you show it, produces the output you give as correct, not the incorrect output you claim it does.

Here's a self-contained demonstration of that:

https://gist.github.com/4056538

Comment: Hey, just added the IndexEntry class since some of you guys asked.  I'm still parsing your responses.

Comment: FOUND THE ANSWER BUT CANT POST IT NORMALLY:


I don't know why, but for some reason:

this.firstOccurrence.equals(other.getFirstOccurrence())

IS NOT EQUIVALENT TO:

this.firstOccurrence == other.getFirstOccurrence()


Changing that line fixed the compareTo method.  I misdiagnosed the problem since every entry was actually getting compared.  Sorry for the misinformation and thank you all for the help!

Comment: Ah, that's because it's an `Integer`, not an `int`. `==` compares objects by identity, not value, and two variables of type `Integer` can refer to objects with the same value which are nonetheless different. Try to avoid using `Integer` for numbers; all sorts of weird things can happen.